# How to check before upload a CSV file to MySQL db if user has selected one

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have simple script that uploads CSV files to a MySQL database. It works ok but if user misses selecting some CSV file to upload and pushes the UPLOAD button, the script tries to insert thousand of 0 lines in the data base.

I wonder if there is a way to check befoere upload file if user has allready selected FILE.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
include("conection.php");  //Connect to Database

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {

    echo "<br><center><p>" . " ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." " . "</p></center>";
                                                            }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
    $count = 0; //skip first line of the CSV file 
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

    if($count) //skip first line of the CSV file 
    {
    $import="INSERT into PAX (name,surname,group) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $count++;
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "<br><center><p>UPLOADED </p></center> ";
    print "<br> ";
    print "<center><a href='index.php'><button>HOME</button</a></center> ";

    //view upload form
    }else {

    print "<center><br><p><b>UPLOAD</b> </p>\n";
    print "<center><br>Select the file for Upload \n";
    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";
    print "<center><input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
    print "<br>";
    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='UPLOAD'></form>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say definitively with your code as it is presented & without seeing the original data, but I believe simply setting a conditional that checks `$data` is enough to prevent the issue you are seeing:

So this line:

```
if ($count) //skip first line of the CSV file {
```

Changes to this:

```
if ($count && !empty($data)) //skip first line of the CSV file {
```

And here is your code adjusted and indents cleaned up for readability.  **EDIT** And I have edited it so there is now a `$SUCCESS_SUBMIT` variable.  That way if the submission is successful & that is `true` or `false` you can act on it.

```
  include("conection.php");  //Connect to Database

  $SUCCESS_SUBMIT = false;
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
      echo "<br><center><p>" . " ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." " . "</p></center>";
    }       

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    $count = 0; //skip first line of the CSV file 

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
      if ($count && !empty($data)) //skip first line of the CSV file {
        $import = "INSERT into PAX (name,surname,group) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        $SUCCESS_SUBMIT = true;
      }
      $count++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }

  if ($SUCCESS_SUBMIT) {
    print "<br><center><p>UPLOADED </p></center> ";
    print "<br> ";
    print "<center><a href='index.php'><button>HOME</button</a></center> ";
  }
  else {
    print "<center><br><p><b>UPLOAD</b> </p>\n";
    print "<center><br>Select the file for Upload \n";
    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";
    print "<center><input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
    print "<br>";
    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='UPLOAD'></form>";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and correction. Now if there is no file selected script doesnt upload anything but Browser get frozen can not go back. There is a way to show user if hasnt selected any csv file give a message file "please select file" or something like this

Comment: JakeGould i will work on your indications !!! Thanks a lot !!!  I appreciate very much your time

Answer (score -1):

"There is a way to show user if hasnt selected any csv file give a message file "please select file" or something like this"

you could use javascript to have a message, if not file selected:

```
print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' 
  onsubmit='return validateUpload();' name='formUpload'
method='post'>";
print "<center><input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
print "<br>";
print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='UPLOAD'></form>";
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" > 
  function validateUpload()
  {
    var fName = document.forms["formUpload"]["filename"].value;
    if (fName==null || fName=="")
    {
      alert("Please select file !");
      return false;
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you advise, i ve adapted the solution that you gave me before and also add this java script just disable to user push UPLOAD button withoud select some file